# Powershell - read from csv and alter value in object then write to new csv file

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file and I want to want to compare the email adresses in the file with the correct email addresses in the AD, if they don't match I want to correct the mail address and then write it all to a new file.

Contents of someFile.csv

```
user_id name            username    email               password    admin
1       Mr Foo          mrFoo1      mrFoo1@domain.com   a           0
2       Ms Bar          msBar2      msBar2@domain.com   a           1
```

Contents of script

```
$current = Import-Csv c:\someFile.csv -Delimiter ";"
$new = @()

foreach($a in $current){
    try {
        if (Get-ADUser $a.username -Properties EmailAddress | where {$_.EmailAddress -eq $null }) {
            <set the field email to N/A>
                    }
        else {
            $realMail =  Get-ADUser $a.username -Properties EmailAddress  | select EmailAddress
            if ($a.email = ($a.username + "@domain.com")) { 
                $a = $a -replace $a.email, $realMail.EmailAddress #does not work
            }
        }
        $new += $a
        }
    catch [exception]{
        $_.Exception.message
    }
}
$new | Select-Object user_id, name, username, email, password, admin | Export-Csv -Path c:\someNewFile.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: When using -replace to replace the faulty email address it does not work as I'd like. Instead of 
<code>
user_id  : 13
name     : Ingrid Name
username : ajaxoi01
email    : AJAXOI01@domain.com
password : a
admin    : 0
</code>
I get
<code>
@{user_id=14; name=Thomas SomeName; username=akesst01; email=TAkesson@domain.com; password=a; admin=0}
</code>

And then I mean the formatting, not the content. It doesn't recognize it as an object any more.

Comment: As you present it someFile.csv is not a CSV file, but a positional fields format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve desired output by changing the line:

```powershell
$a = $a -replace $a.email, $realMail.EmailAddress #does not work
```

to:

```powershell
$a.email = $realMail.EmailAddress
```